# Remove cell editor border in JTable (Windows LaF)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTextField based cell editor that comes with this ugly black border (ignore the caret on the left):

[image]

Is there a way to remove it so it looks similar to this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating the table you can try something like:

```
DefaultCellEditor editor = (DefaultCellEditor)table.getDefaultEditor(Object.class);
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getComponent();
textField.setBorder( null );
```

Edit:

The above approach won't work because the JTable uses a `GenericEditor` which is an inner class of the table that extend the DefaultCellEditor and adds extra functionality for the table.

One piece of functionality added is to manager the Border: "red" for errors and "black" for valid data. So the border is continually being reset by the editor.

Or the other approach would be something like:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setBorder( null );
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor( textField );
table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, editor):
```

Comment: The second approach does exactly what I need, thanks. I thought I'd have to change some of the LaF's settings like some questions I saw regarding the Nimbus LaF.