# Removing the border of a JTextField cell editor doesn't work under certain circumstances

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This question is a follow up of this one due to issues that arose: [Remove cell editor border in JTable (Windows LaF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402153/remove-cell-editor-border-in-jtable-windows-laf)

I am experiencing unexpected behaviour from the `JTextArea` taken from `DefaultCellEditor#getComponent()` when modifying its borders once it's already on the table. The borders simply don't **visually** change.

Even after calling:

`textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(null, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1)));`

and right after that doing:

`System.out.println(textField.getBorder());`

the console shows `javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder@6aff616` which means the border **has changed internally**. However, this isn't reflected visually and I'm very confused.

My test class:

```
public class TableStackOverflow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TableStackOverflow() {
        initComponents();
        prepareTable();
    }

    public void prepareTable() {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Class columnClass = table.getColumnClass(i);
            DefaultCellEditor defaultEditor = (DefaultCellEditor) table.getDefaultEditor(columnClass);
            if (defaultEditor.getComponent() instanceof JTextField) {
                JTextField textField = (JTextField) defaultEditor.getComponent();
                textField.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(null, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1)));
                System.out.println(textField.getBorder());

            }
            defaultEditor.setClickCountToStart(1);
        }
    }

    private void initComponents() {    
        scrPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        table = new org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null},
                {null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "First", "Second"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        table.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(223, 238, 249));
        table.setSelectionForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        scrPane.setViewportView(table);

        getContentPane().add(scrPane, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }                      

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TableStackOverflow().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrPane;
    private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable table;
```

And finally here is a nasty workaround that makes it work but isn't viable:

```
public void prepareTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        DefaultCellEditor defaultEditor = (DefaultCellEditor) table.getDefaultEditor(table.getColumnClass(i));
        if (defaultEditor.getComponent() instanceof JTextField) {
            JTextField textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(null, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1)));
            defaultEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(textField);
            table.setDefaultEditor(table.getColumnClass(i), defaultEditor);
        }
        defaultEditor.setClickCountToStart(1);
    }
}
```

Finally, something much nicer that works (Thanks Camickr!)

```
table.addPropertyChangeListener((evt) -> {
    if ("tableCellEditor".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
        if (table.isEditing()) {
            JTextField jtextField = (JTextField) ((DefaultCellEditor) table.getCellEditor()).getComponent();
            jtextField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DefaultCellEditor defaultEditor = (DefaultCellEditor) table.getDefaultEditor(columnClass);
System.out.println(defaultEditor.getClass());
```

Add the above statement to your code and you will see that the default editor is the `GenericEditor` which is an inner class of the JTable.

This editor adds extra functionality for usage in a JTable.

One of the things it does is manage the Border. If an error is found a "red border" is displayed in the editor. Otherwise the border is set the the default "black border".

> And finally here is a nasty workaround that makes it work but isn't viable:

You either need to use the DefaultCellEditor or create a custom editor.

You might be able to extend the JTable.GenericEditor class and override the `getTableCellEditor(...)` method. This is the method that resets the Border to the default black border.

Or maybe you can override the `getCellEditor(...)` method to the table to get the editor and then remove the border.

Another approach would be to add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the table. Then whenever a cell is edited you will get an event so you can get the active editor and remove its border:

```
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
{
    //  A cell has started/stopped editing

    if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
    {
        if (table.isEditing())
            // add your code here
    }
}
```

Also, why would you use a CompoundBorder to create an EmptyBorder?

Comment: Thank you, again, for taking the time to come up with a detailed answer. I used the `PropertyChangeListener` approach and now it seems to be working. I added it to the main question. Please, if you can, let me know if I implemented it well. Rest assured, in the real world, I'd check if the component of the active editor is of type `JTextArea`, but this was for testing purposes.

Also, using CompoundBorder over EmptyBorder was a sleepy mistake last night so I corrected it.

Comment: Also, any idea how to give an editable JCombobox an EmptyBorder? I did this inside the `PropertyChangeListener`: combobox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()) and I can still see the grey line border.